# Java messaging service queue session

Tags: java, jms, spring-jms

I am new to JMS. I was trying a sample example where in I send a message to a queue in a session and depending on the flag value session is committed. What i expect from the code is, that when my flag is false, the message remains in the queue and does not get deleted. If flag is true, the session gets committed and i get the message. I am not able to do the former part, i.e saving the message in the queue when the flg value is false.

I am using MDPListener and spring framework. Following is my code:

```
public void onMessage(Message message,Session session) {

        System.out.println("New Message arrived part2 .. Passing to Controller");

        Boolean g=false;

        if(g==true)
        {
            System.out.println("Data true..session committed!!");
            try {
                session.commit();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try {
                System.out.println("Sesison not commds!!");

                //HERE I WANT THE CODE TO STORE THE MESSAGE IN THE QUEUE, SO THAT NEXT TIME WHEN THE FLAG IS TRUE, MESSAGE GETS DELIVERED! 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Whenever a message hits a queue, you will have the onMessage called and the message will be delete from the Topic/Queue. ou would have to either renenter the message into the Queue which will again call the onMessage() and might recurse until session is true.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of spring are you using.

Anyways check this out:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?21601-JMS-queue-message-viewing-without-removing-it-from-the-queue

Hope you find it helpful

Comment: i am using spring 3.1.0 version. The point is container does not supports acknowledge method.. i am still not able to do the thing i wanted to do

Answer (score 0):

The container commits the session (unless the listener throws an exception).